# Scanning without requiring any user intervention

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a program that reads a bar code from a scanner and will be saved in a file when a user press "Done" button.

Now, I want to have it automated, when a user scan the bar code, it will automatically be saved in a text file.

Comment: You expect solution written by SO users?

Comment: @spajce I have a multiline textbox that accept the scanned barcode. Then when they are finish, they will click on "Done" button and will be saved on a text file. When I try a single-line textbox, after the scan a barcode they will still need to click the "Done" button to be saved to a text file, is their a method in a textbox that will say "After this scanned, "Done" key is activated?

Comment: first try to check the length of the barcode. `if (barcodeLength >= 5) then saveToFile`

Comment: the barcode differs from product to product, there are 10, 11, or even 15 char length.

Comment: Does/Can your bar code scanner append any characters to the scanned barcode?  I've seen some that can automatically add an asterisk or other character to the end of the barcode when it is scanned.

Comment: im afraid not..but it does go to the next line after every scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the simple logic.

1. Get the length of the barcode
2. Perform Click

   ```
   If barcodeText.Text.Length >= 10 Then
       Call DoneButtonClick(Nothing, Nothing)
   End If
   ```

Comment: Thank you sir, Im using the logic for every possible barcode length..this really helps!